# Working with CrawlSpider

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working on `Crawlspider` which crawls www.flipkart.com and after recursively crawling links within links returns details of all mobiles in that website. All the brands have `href` in this format : `mobiles/samsung~brand/pr?sid=tyy`,4io so I have tried to give the regex to "Rule". Problem is my code is not returning anything. I don't know what is the problem.
My code is:

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from flipkart.items import FlipkartItem

class FlipkartSpider(CrawlSpider):

         name = "flipkart"
         allowed_domains = ["Flipkart.com"]
         start_urls = ["http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles"]
         rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow ="/^([a-z]+)(\/[a-z]{7})(\/[a-z0-9~]+)(\/[a-z\?=0-9,]+)$/"), callback = 'parse_item', follow=True), )

        def parse_item(self, response):
            hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
            titles = hxs.select("//div[@class='product-unit unit-4 browse-product new-design ']")
            items = []
            for titles in titles:
                item = FlipkartItem()
                item ['brand'] = titles.select("//a[@class='fk-display-block nav-section-item tpadding5 bpadding5']/@title").extract()       
                item ['model'] = titles.select("//a[@class='fk-display-block']/text()").extract()
                item ['price'] = titles.select("//span[@class='fk-font-17 fk-bold']/text()").extract()
                item ['description'] = titles.select("//li/span[@class='text']/text()").extract()  
                items.append(item)                                              
                return items
```

I have not done anything in `pipelines.py` and `settings.py`. I have initialized all the parameters in `items.py`. 
Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Can anyone please share his code so that I can have a look or do correction in my code? Please.

Comment: Are you sure that you `Xpath`es are correct and returns desire result? also i think you need to move `return items` out of `for` loop.

Comment: You can check your `xpath`s in [scrapy-shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#scrapy-shell) with doing `$ scrapy shell http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles` then `response.xpath(xpath)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state all links you're interested in have the following format:

`mobiles/samsung~brand/pr?sid=tyy,4io`

And in your code there is the following regex:

`/^([a-z]+)(\/[a-z]{7})(\/[a-z0-9~]+)(\/[a-z\?=0-9,]+)$/`

Please check at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) your regex and you'll see that it does not match the example you provided.

Maybe the following regex does fit your need better: `'sid=tyy,4io'`. At least the spider will crawl the pages (as far as I have tested it).

p.s.: besides the not matching regex there are other problems/errors in your code. First to mention the `for titles in titles:` loop. This error appears quite often in scrapy beginner scripts that are posted on this site. I wonder where all these people get that very same error prone code? So - would you mind to share where you got that part of the code? If we know the source maybe we can correct it.

EDIT (added some code):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join
from scrapy.utils.markup import replace_escape_chars

class FlipkartItem(scrapy.Item):
    brand = scrapy.Field()
    model = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()

class FlipkartSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "flipkart"
    allowed_domains = ["www.flipkart.com"] # filtered offsite request
    start_urls = ["http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles"]
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow ='sid=tyy,4io'),
            callback = 'parse_item',
            follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):

        products = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"product-unit")]')
        for product in products:
            l = ItemLoader(FlipkartItem(), product)
            l.default_input_processor = MapCompose(lambda v: v.split(), replace_escape_chars)
            l.default_output_processor = Join()

            l.add_xpath('model', './/div[contains(@class,"pu-title")]//text()')
            l.add_xpath('price', './/div[contains(@class,"pu-price")]//text()')
            l.add_xpath('description', './/ul[contains(@class,"pu-usp")]//text()')
            yield l.load_item()
```

Comment: Yes sure. I have followed this link http://mherman.org/blog/2012/11/08/recursively-scraping-web-pages-with-scrapy/#.VX7BqUaQmgQ

Comment: If you are getting the proper output, would you please mind sharing your code? So that I can see where I am going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the Link. I'll share the code as soon as I have access to my computer again at the end of the week.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have one more query. How can I store my crawled data into mysql database using python?

Comment: I have tried running my code using 'sid=tyy,4io' regex and it's crawling also but still I am not getting what I want. So can you please help?

Comment: I've added some code that might be helpful for you to understand how you can reach your goal. _P.S.: Probably it is not useful to ask new questions in the comment section. Open a new question for that. Please read the FAQ to learn more about getting most out of this site._

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am new to this so can you explain me what is happening in the following two lines?

Comment: l.default_input_processor = MapCompose(lambda v: v.split(), replace_escape_chars) l.default_output_processor = Join()

Comment: These two lines make sure that the extracted text gets cleaned from whitespace (split) and the output is 'one piece' (join). See the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-input-and-output-processors).

Comment: I have few more questions which I am going to post later so can you please help me in those?

Comment: If my answer solved your question consider to accept the answer by checking the Checkmark on the left side.   If you post a good question there will be someone to help you out.